# Spring Boot 2.1.6 can't start as a SystemD service

Tags: java, spring-boot, systemd, amazon-linux

I'm trying to start a Spring Boot application as a Service on a Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

I'm packaging the service with:

```
$ mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage -Dstart-class=com.acme.MyMicroserviceApplication
```

When i start the service manually(without the service) it runs correclty:

```
$ /usr/bin/java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=pro -server -d64 -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -Xss256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=75 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -jar /home/ec2-user/jars/my-microservice-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar
```

> INFO  [main]
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat
>   started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '' INFO  [main]
>   org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Started
>   FacebookServiceApplication in 12.17 seconds (JVM running for 12.861)
>   INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog:
>   Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet' INFO 
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet: Initializing Servlet
>   'dispatcherServlet' INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet: Completed
>   initialization in 23 ms

But when i start the service, Spring Boot can not find the class:

- org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

The error is:

```
my-microservice[27205]: Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
systemd[1]: squint-facebook.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Unit my-micro.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: my-micro.service failed.
systemd[1]: Stopped my-microservice.
```

My service file is:

- /etc/systemd/system/my-micro.service

---

```
[Unit]
Description=my-microservice
After=syslog.target network.target
Wants=redis.service

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/my-microservice
Environment="JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink $(readlink $(which java)))))"
Environment="PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
Environment="CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib"
Environment="SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=pro"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=pro -server -d64 -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -Xss256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=75 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
User=springboot
# The configuration file application.properties should be here:
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/jars
# Run ExecStartPre with root-permissions
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/my-microservice
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R springboot:syslog /var/log/my-microservice
ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod -R 775 /var/log/my-microservice
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java \
        -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
        -Dspring.profiles.active=pro \
        -server \
        -d64 \
        -Xms256m \
        -Xmx2048m \
        -Xss256m \
        -XX:+UseParallelGC \
        -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048m \
        -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m \
        -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=75 \
        -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
        -jar my-microservice-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutStopSec=20
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=0
StartLimitBurst=10
SyslogIdentifier=my-microservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

The pom.xml file of my project is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.teamknowlogy.squint</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-microservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>my-microservice</name>
    <description>...</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-session.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</spring-session.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <!-- The main class to start by executing "java -jar" -->
        <start-class>com.acme.MyMicroserviceApplication</start-class>
        <spring.boot.mainclass>com.acme.MyMicroserviceApplication</spring.boot.mainclass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-loader -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>aws-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/bom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://spring.io/projects/spring-session -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-session-bom</artifactId>
                <version>Bean-SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Version of Java:

```
$ /usr/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_201"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Version of the Amazon Linux instance:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use shell parameter expansion (`$`) in your Unit file Environment configuraton:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/my-microservice
Environment="JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink $(readlink $(which java)))))"
Environment="PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
Environment="CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib"
Environment="SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=pro"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=pro -server -d64 -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -Xss256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=75 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

[Systemd doesn't support shell parameter expansion](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment):

> Environment= Sets environment variables for executed processes. Takes
>   a space-separated list of variable assignments. This option may be
>   specified more than once, in which case all listed variables will be
>   set. If the same variable is set twice, the later setting will
>   override the earlier setting. If the empty string is assigned to this
>   option, the list of environment variables is reset, all prior
>   assignments have no effect. Variable expansion is not performed inside
>   the strings, however, specifier expansion is possible. **The $ character
>   has no special meaning.** If you need to assign a value containing
>   spaces or the equals sign to a variable, use double quotes (") for the
>   assignment.

I would suggest to define the environment variables in a usual `setenv.sh` file of the application.